# unable to plugin TESTNG in eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng

I need to automate android app using Appium automation tool with Eclipse as IDE.
Approach followed:

1. had set-up   java
2. downloaded appium for windows installation - and set java path
3. downloaded android SDK for windows - set android home path
4. opened sdk manager folder and installed all the uninstalled packages.
5. Started adding plugins to the ECLIPSE that came along with the ADT bundle ( in step 3)
6. install TESTNG thro ADT help- install new software with the use of link:http://beust.com/eclipse and eclipse re-started after the installation.
7. When observed the Show View - Other- didnot find TESTNG option 
   configuarions :
   Eclipse Release 4.2.0
   TESTNG 6.9.9.201510270734 is in the already installed list of plug-ins, but not able to view in Show View /Run menu.

Comment: do right click on your class and see if you are getting testNG option or not?

Comment: not getting testNG option

Comment: Ok , go to Eclipse then options : Window -> Preferences and see if you are getting TestNG option or not? It seems your TESTNG is not installed properly.

Comment: No, checked all the options. didnt work

Comment: Then testNG is not installed properly in your eclipse. Please follow these steps to install it : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/

Comment: the error im getting is " The operation cannot be completed. TestNG will be ignored because it is already installed".

Comment: Tried alternatively by doing uninstall and again install, even then Eclipse is not displaying TestNG option in any of the menu tabs

Comment: what is your eclipse version?

Comment: Eclipse Release 4.2.0. It is within the downalod package of the adt bundle for windows. adt is the android development tool. I want to plugin TestNG for the writing the test-scripts for the android apps.

Comment: you should try in another machine. Not sure why testNG is not working..it should work.

Comment: ok             fine will try